# Update-Database connects to wrong database

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, package-manager-console

I set connection string in my Startup.cs (Startup class and ConfigureServices method). Sample code below:

```
if (_currentEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
    connectionString = "ProdConnection string here ..";
}
else
{
    connectionString = "Devl connection string here ...";
}
```

In the Package Manager Consoler of my Visual Studio 2017, when I do an `Update-Database -Migration someMigration` it always applies it to Devl database even when the environment is set to production.

How can I force it to connect to production?

Comment: Instead you can specify `-ConnectionStringName` argument

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, I don't see that option for ef-core here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell Are you sure that exists?

Answer (score 0):

The hosting environment uses environment variables to determine the current environment. In the package management console, be sure to set this environment variable before running the EF Core commands:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"
```

Comment: I already tried this approach but it didn't help. Unfortunately there is no way to see the connection string even with -verbose option so I couldn't debug why.